# How can I automate a browser to visit 1000 pages and trigger a simple javascript function on each page?

Tags: javascript, browser, automation, browser-automation

I need to load 1000 urls on a tracking/reporting app (after authenticating via an HTML form) and trigger a "resubmit" javascript function.  Unfortunately there is no bulk action to handle all at once so I'm left with automation.  What are my options?

```
http://domain.com/0001.php
http://domain.com/0002.php
http://domain.com/0003.php
...
http://domain.com/1000.php
```

Each of the above pages has a resubmit() javascript function triggered by a href.  How can I automate triggering these?

**Example:**

```
<form action="/resubmit" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="security_token" value="SUPER-LONG-HASH">
  <input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://mysite.com/0001.html">
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="long-string">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window["resubmit"] = function () {
      document["resubmit"].submit();
      return false;
    }
  </script>
  <a href="javascript:resubmit()" class="resubmit-class">resubmit</a>
</form>
```

I'm on a Mac.  Unix, Perl, Bash, PHP, Automator, FireFox iMarcos are all available.

Comment: Have you thought about [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)?

Comment: Can you just call the url on each page directly that the resubmit would call?

Comment: Why can't each page run the resubmit() function onload?

Comment: Updated question to provide a bit more context of the actual script that's run.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did I get a bunch of down votes for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already voted up the other answers, but in the end I wound up using straight AppleScript.  This was helpful because it used an existing session so I didn't have to deal with any authentication problems.  Thanks for all of your help, everyone.  I look forward to becoming familiar with the tools you shared.

```
set thePath to (path to desktop as Unicode text) & "list_of_urls.txt"
set theFile to (open for access file thePath)
set theContent to (read theFile)
close access theFile

set theURLs to every paragraph of theContent

tell application "Safari"
    repeat with theURL in theURLs
        make new document
        set URL of front document to theURL
        delay 5
        set theScript to "document.getElementsByClassName('resubmit-class')[0].click();"
        do JavaScript theScript in current tab of first window
        do JavaScript "window.resubmit()" in front document
        delay 5
        close front document
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution - I think you're right that authentication is probably the trickiest issue here.

Comment: Thanks Nick.  I am interested in getting to know Pjscrape though.  Seems like a helpful tool to have in my belt.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3):

You should check out [PhantomJS](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/), "a headless WebKit with JavaScript API". It allows you to run a WebKit browser instance from the command line and execute Javascript.

You might be able to save some time using [Pjscrape](http://nrabinowitz.github.com/pjscrape/), a tool built on top of PhantomJS that can spider multiple pages or take a long list of URLs (disclaimer: this is my project). I haven't tried it with 1,000+ URLs, but I think you could do what you describe with the following 6 lines:

```
pjs.addSuite({
    urls: [...], // your very long list here
    scraper: function() {
        window.resubmit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Nick.  Can you tell me how I can first login to the webapp via Pjscrape?  I don't see any documentation on this.  It works wonderfully for pure public pages though.  Definitely useful for future projects.  I just wish I could figure it out for this one.  Maybe with the bookmarklet?

Comment: Hmm, you didn't mention that you needed authentication - that definitely complicates things. HTTP auth, or a login form in the app?

Comment: It's a HTML login form. Could this be executed from inside the browser via the bookmarklet? I was a bit confused about how to activate it and use in the console. What console? Where can I see this? Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I would use Ruby+[Watir](http://watir.com/) for that. Example code (not tested):

```
require "watir-webdriver"
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

urls = ["http://domain.com/0001.php", "http://domain.com/0002.php"] # add more URLs here
urls.each do |url|
  browser.goto url
  browser.a(:text => "resubmit").click
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you, but you could try [Fake](http://fakeapp.com/). I think it would allow you to automate submitting the form and make a loop.

Comment: Fake is very interesting.  I have successfully submitted the javascript on a page but haven't figured out how to loop through urls yet.  Any tips?

Comment: I haven't tried multiple URLs in it, but my understanding is it's just running JS, so you should be able to create an array and loop through it?